# Why does my computer shut down when I login with TightVNC or LogMeIn?

Tags: vnc, shutdown, logmein, tightvnc

Whenever I try to remote control a computer at home from my office, it always shuts down automatically for no reason.

I normally use VNC or LogMeIn for remote control of the home computer, which has a security camera system running on it.

Does anyone know why the system would keep shutting down in this way?

Comment: Does it really happen with both LogMein **and** VNC?

Comment: yes it does. but it work fine before I install a security camera software, on the software, I couldn't fine any setting relate to that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you log in locally?

If this is happening with both Log Me In and VNC, something tells me that it could be an issue with the machine itself - either a prankster has put a shutdown command in startup or it could be something such as Windows activation logging you off.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the advice. could you tell me where I can check it and fix it please? the computer is  running Window XP. many thanks!

Comment: sorry, it can't be remote locally as well.